# Implementing a UITabBar in my working Three20 application

Tags: iphone, three20

I have a working application using Three20.  It basically is a bunch of nested TTableView's.

I would like to add a UITabBar to the bottom of my app, but am not sure how to start.  I used the Three20 project templates available at [Three20.info](http://three20.info/setup/templates)

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the [`TTNavigatorDemo`](http://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples/TTNavigatorDemo/Classes/) that ships with three20.  In particular, notice [`TabBarController.m`](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/samples/TTNavigatorDemo/Classes/TabBarController.m), and its interaction with [`AppDelegate`](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/samples/TTNavigatorDemo/Classes/AppDelegate.m).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't look at the samples first. :-)